# Trying to set an icon extracted from a file to a TreeView Node.Image using API functions

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, icons, api-design

I'm creating a userform for users in my department that will allow them to select files/subfolders from templates to create a working folder. This is done using VBA7 through Excel 2010 (the only tool available for this department...) on a Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit desktop. Bare bones, it works great.  I've even used other API functions successfully to make the Excel userform appear to the user like it's own standalone application.  Now I'm just trying to add some file icons to make it a little easier (and prettier) for the users to visualize.

The logic of adding the icons during userform initialization boils down to:

1) Populate a dictionary of file template source paths at run time

2) Populate a TreeView with nodes that represent the files by using this dictionary

3) Use the same file paths in the dictionary to assign icons to each node by using API functions to extract icons from the files

I've browsed a lot of forums and code databases on using API functions to extract icons from files and converting them somehow into a usable image for the userform controls. I've experimented with several functions and constant values and combinations of each. But I hit a wall months ago, and I've routinely been banging my head against it with no progress.

Below is the relevant code from an API module I've set up in the workbook, cut down to the be easily copied into a new module, in a new workbook, with a fresh userform module that contains only a new TreeView control. It's pretty much copypasta from forums and heavily annotated for my own sake. The comments should also explain my reasoning, which might be incorrect. Finally, I've also noted ('NOTE - ...) issues and variations to the code in some comments.

```
Option Explicit


'Function GetFileIcon constants and variables
    'Constants define values in UDT and enum variables
    'Variables used in function parameters and declared function SHGetFileInfo,
    '   which is called by GetFileIcon
    Private Const MAX_PATH              As Long = 260
    Private Const SHGFI_ICON            As Long = &H100
    Private Const SHGFI_SMALLICON       As Long = &H1
    Private Const SHGFI_LARGEICON       As Long = &H0

    'Structure that contains file info
    Private Type SHFILEINFO
        'Handle to the file icon
        hIcon                           As Long

        'Icon image index within system image list
        iIcon                           As Long

        'Flag for one or more file attribute
        dwAttributes                    As Long

        'Path and file name as it appears in the Windows shell
        szDisplayName                   As String * MAX_PATH

        'File type description
        szTypeName                      As String * 80
    End Type

    'Icon size in pixels
    Public Enum isccIconSizeConst
        '32x32 icon
        isccLargeIcon = SHGFI_LARGEICON

        '16x16 icon
        isccSmallIcon = SHGFI_SMALLICON
    End Enum

    'Icon type, seems to be defined by usage
    Public Enum itccIconTypeConst
        'Normal icon, unclear how normal is defined
        itccNormalIcon = SHGFI_ICON
    End Enum

'UDT that stores a Globally Unique IDentifier (GUID), a 128-bit integer
    '   used to identify resources
    'Used by function IconToPicture and declared function
    '   OleCreatePictureIndirect, which is called by IconToPicture
    Private Type GUID
        Data1                           As Long
        Data2                           As Integer
        Data3                           As Integer
        Data4(0 To 7)                   As Byte
    End Type

'Conditional compilation of API declared functions, evaluating
    '   Version of VBA installed (VBA7 or VBA6) and
    '   Windows system type (64- or 32-bit environment)
    'Compatibility of long variable type (Long vs LongPtr), library file,
    '   and alias within the library file vary with VBA version and Windows
    '   system type
    #If VBA7 Then
        'UDT that stores bitmap info
            'Used by function IconToPicture and declared function
            '   OleCreatePictureIndirect, which is called by IconToPicture
            'Long variable type of some elements varies depending VBA version
        Private Type uPicDesc
            cbSize                      As Long     'Size of structure
            picType                     As Long     'Type of picture
            hImage                      As LongPtr  'Handle to image
            hPal                        As LongPtr  'Handle to palette
        End Type

        #If Win64 Then 'also VBA7
            'Convert a handle into an Object Linking and Embedding (OLE)
                '   IPicture interface object
                'IPicture parameter type is an interface that manages a picture
                '   object and its properties
                'Called by IconToPicture
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect _
                Lib "oleaut32.dll" ( _
                    ByRef PicDesc As uPicDesc, _
                    ByRef RefIID As GUID, _
                    ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As LongPtr, _
                    ByRef IPic As IPicture) _
                As LongPtr

        #Else 'Win32 and VBA7
            'See previous instance of function for description
            Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect _
                Lib "olepro32.dll" ( _
                    ByRef PicDesc As uPicDesc, _
                    ByRef RefIID As GUID, _
                    ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As LongPtr, _
                    ByRef IPic As IPicture) _
                As LongPtr
'NOTE - assuming that "oleaut32.dll" is the only option available for Win32
    'This shouldn't be a factor currently since the machine used runs Win64

        #End If 'the following are Win32 or Win64 but still VBA7

        'Get the handle of an icon from an executable file (EXE),
            '   dynamic-link library (DLL), or icon file (ICO)
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function ExtractIcon _
            Lib "SHELL32.DLL" Alias "ExtractIconA" ( _
                ByVal hInst As LongPtr, _
                ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, _
                ByVal nIconIndex As Long) _
            As LongPtr

        'Get info about an object in the file system (e.g. file, folder,
            '   directory, drive root)
            'Description of parameters
            '   spszPath, string that contains file path and name,
            '       absolute or relative
            '   dwFileAttributes, flags that represent what file info to assume
            '   psfi, SHFILEINFO structure that contains file info
            '   cbFileInfo, file size in bytes of the SHFILEINFO structure
            '   uFlags, flags that represent what file info to retrieve
            'To get info from existing file system object
            '   pszPath must be a valid path or name
            '   dwFileAttributes value is ignored, set to 0
            '   psfi must be empty SHFILEINFO variable
            '   cbFileInfo should be LenB of psfi
            '   uFlags should be variable with flags added via
            '       bitwise operation
            'To get info from file type/extension in general
            '   pszPath can be just the file extension
            '   dwFileAttributes must include FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
            '   psfi must be empty SHFILEINFO variable
            '   cbFileInfo should be LenB of psfi
            '   uFlags must include SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES, along with flags
            '       that represent what file info to retrieve
            'Microsoft suggests that, if this function returns an icon
            '   handle, freeing system memory after with DestroyIcon function
            'Called by GetFileIcon
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetFileInfo _
            Lib "Shell32" Alias "SHGetFileInfoA" ( _
                ByVal pszPath As String, _
                ByVal dwFileAttributes As LongPtr, _
                ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, _
                ByVal cbFileInfo As LongPtr, _
                ByVal uFlags As LongPtr _
            ) As LongPtr

    #Else 'VBA6 or earlier, either Win32 or Win64
        'See previous instance of UDT for description
        Private Type uPicDesc
            cbSize                          As Long
            picType                         As Long
            hImage                          As Long
            hPal                            As Long
        End Type

        'See previous instance of function for description
        Private Declare Function ExtractIcon _
            Lib "SHELL32.DLL" Alias "ExtractIconA" ( _
                ByVal hInst As Long, _
                ByVal lpszExeFileName As String, _
                ByVal nIconIndex As Long) _
            As Long

        'See previous instance of function for description
        Private Declare Function SHGetFileInfo _
            Lib "Shell32" Alias "SHGetFileInfoA" ( _
                ByVal pszPath As String, _
                ByVal dwFileAttributes As Long, _
                ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, _
                ByVal cbFileInfo As Long, _
                ByVal uFlags As Long) _
            As Long

        'See previous instance of function for description
        Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect _
            Lib "oleaut32.dll" ( _
                ByRef PicDesc As uPicDesc, _
                ByRef RefIID As GUID, _
                ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, _
                ByRef IPic As IPicture) _
            As Long
    #End If


Public Sub TestPopulateTreeView(ByRef rtvwView As MSComctlLib.TreeView)
    'Set TreeView nodes and node properties
    'Called by UserForm_Initialize event
        'Assume simple UserForm with single TreeView control
    'Arguments for TreeView.Nodes.Add:
        'Relative
            'String that matches the key of the parent
        'Relationship
            'tvwFirst , tvwLast, tvwNext, tvwPrevious, tvwChild
            'If tvwChild, then Relative is required
        'key
            'Unique string
        'Text
            'String to be displayed in the tree
        'Image
            'Index in an ImageList control, shown by default
        'SelectedImage
            'Index in an ImageList control, shown when selected

    Dim varKey                          As Variant
    Dim imlTvw                          As MSComctlLib.ImageList

    Set imlTvw = New MSComctlLib.ImageList

    'Set TreeView properties
    With rtvwView
        'Clear the TreeView of existing nodes
        .Nodes.Clear

        'Turn on checkboxes so user can select options
        .CheckBoxes = True

        'Set the behavior of the branch lines
            'Tree lines disables any collapsing of the tree
            'Root lines allow the tree to be collapsed at root level
        .LineStyle = tvwTreeLines

        'Set style of branch lines to exclude minimize and maximize buttons
        .Style = tvwTreelinesText

        'Set the behavior of the node text
            'Manual prevents user from editing the text in the tree
            'Automatic allows user to edit the text in the tree
        .LabelEdit = tvwManual
    End With

    'Build ImageList of icons for use in the TreeView
    With imlTvw.ListImages
        'Extract the icon from a simple MS Word document
        .Add 1, "test1", _
            GetFileIcon("C:\Temp\New Microsoft Word Document.docx")
'NOTE - after this line, values for imlTvw.ListImages.Item(1).Picture from
    'the variable Watch window are:
    '   Handle = 10-digit integer
    '       varies as I experiment with source files, which is expected
    '   Height = 423
    '       I assumed this would be 16, given that the
    '       GetFileIcon iscIconSize = isccSmallIcon = 16
    '   hPal = <Automation error>
    '       that "value" is  what the Watch window reports verbatim
    '       I strongly suspect this is what's causing the issue
    '   Type = 3
    '       I honestly don't know if this is correct, but the one site that
    '       addressed it has named the constant vbPicTypeIcon, seemed relevant
    '   Width = 423
    '       same thing as Height, I assumed this would be 16
    End With

    'Set ImageList to TreeView
    Set rtvwView.ImageList = imlTvw

    'Populate node(s) in TreeView
    With rtvwView
        'Create node with no parent, added to root level
        .Nodes.Add _
            Relationship:=tvwNext, _
            key:="node1"

        'Set node default properties
        With .Nodes("node1")
            .Checked = True
            .Text = "node1"
            .Expanded = True
            .Image = 1
'NOTE - there is no error after setting the .Image property, but once the
    'UserForm is loaded, there is no icon image displayed in the TreeView
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetFileIcon( _
        ByVal strPath As String, _
        Optional ByVal iscIconSize As isccIconSizeConst = isccSmallIcon, _
        Optional ByVal itcIconType As itccIconTypeConst = itccNormalIcon) _
    As IPicture
    'Retrieve the icon associated to a file/folder
    'Return the description of the specified file/folder
        'For example "Folder", "Executable File", "Bmp Image", etc
    'Uses the IconToPicture function
'NOTE - also tried StdPicture and IPictureDisp types

    Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL         As Long = &H80
    Const SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES       As Long = &H10

    Dim sfiInfo                         As SHFILEINFO
    Dim lngIconType                     As Long

    'Set the icon flag to include size and normal type
        'Overrides any other type accidentally passed to function when called
    If itcIconType = itccNormalIcon Then
        lngIconType = iscIconSize Or itcIconType
    Else
        lngIconType = iscIconSize Or itccNormalIcon
    End If

    'Retrieve the file's icon handle
    Call SHGetFileInfo(strPath, 0, sfiInfo, LenB(sfiInfo), lngIconType)
'NOTE - also tried retrieving from the general file type/extension
    'defined by the system:
'    Call SHGetFileInfo(strPath, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, sfiInfo, LenB(sfiInfo), _
'        SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES Or lngIconType)

'    'Convert the icon handle to a picture object
    Set GetFileIcon = IconToPicture(sfiInfo.hIcon)
'TESTING, trying out extracticon to see if that has better luck

'NOTE - also tried replacing the code above with an alternative method,
    'retrieving an icon from an executable using another API function:
'
'    Dim lngIcon As Long
'
'    'Retrieve icon handle from an executable
'    lngIcon = ExtractIcon(0, "xwizard.exe", 0)
'
'    'Convert the icon handle to a picture object
'    Set GetFileIcon = IconToPicture(lngIcon)

End Function

Public Function IconToPicture( _
        hIcon As Long) _
    As IPicture
    'Convert an icon handle into a picture object

    'Constant sourced on 2019-11-22 from
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507385
        '   /how-do-i-convert-a-stdole-stdpicture-to-a-different-type
    Const vbPicTypeIcon                 As Long = 3

    Dim pic                             As uPicDesc
    Dim IID_IDispatch                   As GUID
    Dim ipdIcon                         As IPicture
    Dim lngResult                       As Long

    'Initialize the uPicDesc structure
    With pic
        .cbSize = LenB(pic)
        .picType = vbPicTypeIcon
        .hImage = hIcon
'NOTE - hPal is not set and defaults to 0
    End With

    'Create the interface GUID
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H20400
        .Data4(0) = &HC0
        .Data4(7) = &H46
    End With
'NOTE - this is the most common GUID I've found across forums
    'I have also encountered and tried the following one, sourced from
    'http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php
    '   ?770797-How-do-I-use-OleCreatePictureIndirect
'    With IID_IDispatch
'        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
'        .Data2 = &HBF32
'        .Data3 = &H101A
'        .Data4(0) = &H8B
'        .Data4(1) = &HBB
'        .Data4(2) = &H0
'        .Data4(3) = &HAA
'        .Data4(4) = &H0
'        .Data4(5) = &H30
'        .Data4(6) = &HC
'        .Data4(7) = &HAB
'    End With

    'Create the picture and return an object reference as the function result
    lngResult = OleCreatePictureIndirect(pic, IID_IDispatch, True, ipdIcon)

    'Confirm that the image was captured before setting function to picture
    If lngResult = 0 Then
        Set IconToPicture = ipdIcon
    End If
'NOTE - assuming that 0 means successful
    'found return value names (but no numeric values) listed at
    'http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/OleCreatePictureIndirect.shtml

End Function
```

This whole icon thing isn't even a priority. The image icons are, and always were, a "nice to have." But it's been so long and I've spent so much effort trying to figure it out that it's now a vendetta. I'm desperate to know what is wrong in my code for the sake of my sanity; it's become my white whale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the icons, chanage this line

```
.Style = tvwTreelinesText
```

To this one:

```
.Style = tvwTreelinesPictureText
```

Comment: I shelved this entire project for most of the year and only recently dusted it off to continue working on it.  Then I noticed your answer -  months later - and it worked like a charm! What a stupid oversight on my part lol